# Using arrays in jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Friend,
I have a calender and I am using JQuery. In order to disable a day we use this function:

```
$('$ids').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        //alert(date.getDate());
        //console.log(jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day));
        console.log(jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day));
        if (date.getDay()==5 ||( date.getMonth()==$month && date.getDate() == $day)))

            return [false, '', 'weekends'];
        return [true];
    }
});
```

Where $day and $month are the day and month to be disabled which are passed from a PHP function. However, when I wan to disable several days, I pass an array to the function, and I use function jQuery.inarray() but it does not work. The problematic code is:

```
$('$ids').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        //alert(date.getDate());
        //console.log(jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day));
         console.log(date.getDate());
        console.log(jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day));
        if (date.getDay()==5 ||( date.getMonth()==$month && !jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day)))

            return [false, '', 'weekends'];
        return [true];
    }
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.inArray` actually returns the index in the array if found, or `-1` if it's not in there.  Doing `!jQuery.inArray()` is *incorrect* as `0` is a valid return value.  `0` means it *was* found in the array, and it's the 1st element.

Comment: What @RocketHazmat is saying is replace `&& !jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day)` with `&& jQuery.inArray(date.getDate() , $day) == -1`

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but it still returns -1 for all values. I put $day=array(2,25) but it returns -1 even for 2 and 25. I do not know why.

Comment: So, `$day` is a PHP variable?

Comment: yes, this is a php class, a function of which returns a jquery function. This is a php variable used in the jQuery functio n.

Comment: You can't just mix and match PHP and JS variables. Remember that all the PHP code will run, send its output (text) to the browser, and the browser will then interpret that text as HTML and JS, and only then will any JS code actually execute.

Comment: You mean I have to convert the original php array into a jquery array? then how can I do it? I used             var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo (json_encode(date);) ?> but it did not work.

Comment: @Amir_Controller: How did it "not work"?  What did it do?  What happened?